# How to express 'unneed' of something?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, expressions

For example, method 1 of doing something (say A) requires something else (say B). And I invented method 2 to do A but without the prerequisite of B. I can say:

> The disadvantage of method 1 is its requirement/need of B.

Now I want to introduce my method by saying

> the advantage of my method 2 is its (the phrase).

What should I put in there to represent the meaning of "no requirement/need of B"?

I don't choose to say "the advantage of my method 2 is that it doesn't require B" because I want to also introduce other advantages, like "the advantage of my method 2 is its speed, efficiency, and … ". What should I put here?

Comment: ... the fact that ... (You also need 'advantages'.)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, james. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "obviate" may sound a bit out of place, but you could try this.

```
"The advantage of my method 2 is it obviates B."
```

or

```
"The advantage of my method 2 is its speed, efficiency, and obviation of B."
```

You also have the option of this semi-quick-and-dirty line:

```
"The advantage of my method 2 is its speed, efficiency, and lack of B as a requirement."
```

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, jsng. We appreciate your input. :)

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of my method 2 is that it...

- makes "B" redundant (or superfluous).
- moots "B" (or makes "B" moot).
- eliminates the contingency on "B".
- takes "B" out of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think the natural choice is ***elimination***. You could use *its elimination of B*, *its elimination of the need of B* or *its elimination of the prerequisite of B*. But they are all too wordy.

If you want a concise sentence, I recommend to rephrase it, and use either **fewer steps** or **fewer prerequisites** instead.

> The advantage of my method 2 is its fewer steps, speed, efficiency, and … ".

Answer (score -1):

Method 2 removes the requirement for B and has the advantage of ....

Comment: This is more of a "comment" than an answer, the probable reason for your downvote.